# Stopping user from gaining access to SSH after making FTP account

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ftp

I am making users an FTP account on some remote servers, but i don't want them to have access to SSH, only FTP.

How is this possible on Ubuntu, running pureftpd?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add the directive `DenyUsers user1 user2 ...`.  Alternatively, if all the users who shouldn't have SSH access are part of the same group (say ftpusers) you can use `DenyGroups ftpusers`.  Then restart sshd with `/etc/init.d/sshd restart`

Answer (score 2):

Use virtualusers, which in ftp lingo is a ftp user that does not have a shell account. This is far better than trying to deny ssh on a per-user basis.

[some guide i googled](http://go2linux.garron.me/linux/2010/05/how-install-secure-pure-ftp-server-chrooted-virtual-users-743)